# List subfolders somewhere in the path with rsync

Tags: networking, rsync, regex

I'm developing a program, that will recursively "walk" through Linux repositories, look for PXE-related files and create gPXE configs.

I met across a problem with the structure of Ubuntu catalogs on mirrors. I need to recach this directory, for instacne: `/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/`

As we can see, there are numerous variable directories: `precise`, `installer-$ARCH` and `$arch`

I don't know why, but my rsync config doesn't match any `current/images` subfolder.
UPD:

```
+ dists/
+ dists/*
+ dists/*/main/
+ dists/*/main/*
+ dists/*/main/*/current
+ dists/*/main/*/current/
+ dists/*/main/*/current/images
+ dists/*/main/*/current/images/***
- *
```

UPD: now it fails at `/current` directory. If I put current with slash in the end, I don't receive it with rsync, so it stops one directory up. This or that rsync doesn't go deeper than current, so I won't get any `images` with current config.

I don't want any non-current configs. How do I properly create a config to include only `main` and only `netboot`  and its contents.

UPD: rsync command is `rsync -r --no-motd --include-from=newinclude rsync://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu`

SOLUTION:
Ok, fine!

The problem was that Ubuntu use a friendly-way of representing of current build and version, keeping it with current symlink. If you start rsync with -l flag you'll see that it's a link to one of the directories in installer

```
 lrwxrwxrwx dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current -> 20101020ubuntu300
```

Comment: What does the exact rsync command line look like?

Comment: @quadruplebucky updated post

Comment: what happens if you just have one line: +  dists/*/main/*/current/images/**  (note two asterisks at end)

Comment: @quadruplebucky lists everything right from dists and below

Comment: What is your aim? do you want to create and update package repository?